# java sax parse not well formed xml

Tags: java, rss, sax, well-formed

I am implementing an RSS search feature from a search engine, using Java and SAX. However, some search results are not well-formed, i.e. the body of the `<title>` tag of some entries contains the `&` character instead of `&amp;` etc (e.g. something like, let's say, `Starsky & Hutch`).

When parsing the RSS, I get a `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser&ParseException`, causing the whole search to interrupt and return nothing.

I want my parser to work around these errors, like Firefox's RSS reader does. What are the posibilities to fix this issue and parse the RSS feed?

Comment: How about an RSS feed parser? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+rss+parser

Comment: If it's not well-formed, then it's not an RSS feed. A pedantic point, but a crucial one.

Comment: @skaffman I agree with you. But this leaves me no choice but to abandon that feed. Too bad, although it's their fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAX implementations are typically designed to detect errors and throw exceptions, and there is no standard way to work around this. The most reasonable thing I can think of is to try to patch the errors, such as stray & characters, before streaming to SAX.